# subsetting data frame by row index

Tags: r

Why is my last step converting the data frame to a vector? I want to keep the first 6000 observations in the data frame `key`.

```
  set.seed(1)
  key <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10000, ncol = 1))
  names(key) <- "ID"
  key$ID <- replicate(10000, 
                      rawToChar(as.raw(sample(c(48:57,65:90,97:122), 8, replace=T))))
  key <- unique(key)  # still a data frame
  key <- key[1:6000,] # no longer a data frame
```

Comment: `is.data.frame(key[1:6000,,drop=F])
[1] TRUE`

Comment: You can just use key <- data.frame(key[1:6000,]) if that's all you need

Comment: @oliver13 that does work, but I'm not clear why I need it. Shouldn't `key[1:6000,]` be sufficient to subset the data frame?

Comment: @akrun, that works. is this the same as `?drop`? I checked the help for this, but I'm not certain what `drop=F` does, besides give the correct result.

Comment: @Eric Green. Please check `?Extract` `drop: For matrices and arrays.  If ‘TRUE’ the result is coerced to
          the lowest possible dimension (see the examples).  This only
          works for extracting elements, not for the replacement.  See
          ‘drop’ for further details.`

Comment: Ok, getting closer, @akrun. If I add a second column, maybe `key[,2] <- 2` before I try to subset, `key <- key[1:6000,]` keeps `key` a data frame without having to specify `drop=F`. Why do I need `drop=F` when `length(key)==1` but not when `length(key)==2`?

Comment: @NerdLife's answer clarifies

Comment: @Eric Green. If you have only one column, as mentioned in the documentation, it gets coerced to lowest dimension ie. a vector `is.vector(key)
[1] TRUE`, which is not the case when you have more than one columns.

Comment: @akrun, if you make `key[1:6000,,drop=F]` the answer, I'll accept it. I'll check back in a few days and add this answer if I don't see one just to make sure it gets closed. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 key1 <- key[1:6000,,drop=F] #should prevent the data.frame from converting to a vector.
```

According to the documentation of `?Extract.data.frame`

> drop:  logical.  If ‘TRUE’ the result is coerced to the lowest
>             possible dimension.  The default is to drop if only one
>             column is left, but *not* to drop if only one row is left.

Or, you could use `subset`, but usually, this is a bit slower.  Here the row.names are numbers from `1` to `10000`

```
 key2 <- subset(key, as.numeric(rownames(key)) <6000)

 is.data.frame(key2)
 #[1] TRUE
```

because,

```
 ## S3 method for class 'data.frame'
 subset(x, subset, select, drop = FALSE, ...) #by default it uses drop=F
```

Answer (score 0):

It's being coerced to a vector basically because it can be and [that's the default](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html) coercion when there's only 1 element. R is trying to be "helpful".

This will keep it as a dataframe:

```
set.seed(1)
key <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10000, ncol = 1))
names(key) <- "ID"
key$ID <- replicate(10000, 
                      rawToChar(as.raw(sample(c(48:57,65:90,97:122), 8, replace=T))))
key <- unique(key)  
key <- as.data.frame(key[1:6000,]) # still a data frame
```

Comment: this works, but I prefer `key[1:6000,,drop=F]` because it keeps my column name. `as.data.frame(key[1:6000,])` changes the name.

Comment: @EricGreen OK, fair enough